# How to get reference count of a PyObject?

Tags: python, c++, c, python-c-api, python-internals

How to get reference count of a `PyObject` from C++?

There are functions `Py_INCREF` and `Py_DECREF` which increase/decrease it, but I haven't found any function which return object's reference count.

I need it for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reference count of each and every object is stored in the `PyObject` itself, in a variable called [`ob_refcnt`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37d896c3604a/Include/object.h#l107). You can directly access that.

```
typedef struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;          # Reference count
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
} PyObject;
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`Py_REFCNT` Macro](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37d896c3604a/Include/object.h#l116).

Comment: I would better rely on the macro than internal struct members that are probably not guaranteed not to change..